# Yii2 gridview search form filter from another table result

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add a search form on my grid view 
In search from, I have dropdown field according to each selection in dropdown I want to filter my gridview.
for example when I select equal in the dropdown and then type 2 in my question amount input, grid view show member that ask two questions. 
also, I join three table 
in the search model I add:

```
$query->joinWith(['base_user']);
$query->joinWith(['question']);
```

and

```
'question' =>function($r){
    if ($this->questionCount == User::ASKED_QUESTION_EQUAL) {
        if ($this->questionCount == User::ASKED_QUESTION_EQUAL) {
            $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(`tbl_question`.`create_user_id`)
                ->from('{{%question}}')
                ->leftJoin('{{%user}}','{{%question}}.create_user_id = {{%user}}.user_id')
                ->groupBy(`{{%question}}.create_user_id`)
                ->having(['create_user_id'=>$this->user_id])
                ->count();
            if ($this->questionAmount = $rows){
                $r->andFilterWhere(['=', 'questionAmount', $rows]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get

> Database Exception error Unknown column 'questionAmount' in 'where clause'

also I add questionAmount on my question model

if I change last code to:

```
$query->andFilterWhere('LIKE',$this->askedQuestionAmount, $rows);
```

I get error again

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `questionAmount` is db field?

Comment: show your `Question` model